# How can I stringify any type of value the same way console.log does?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

Like the title says, how can I stringify a value of any type and get the exact same output console.log would print, or a very similar and still useful print, in a variable, instead of going to the console. Preferably in Deno.

`.toString()` works nice on `Error()` and other similar functions, but returns `[object Object]` on your more traditional objects. Likewise, `JSON.stringify()` works nice on your more traditional objects, but returns `{}` on stuff like `Error()`. Since these are both objects, I'm basically wondering, what would be the best way to get the most optimal output with objects, when you don't know beforehand what type it will be.

Comment: With `String(error)` you will get something close to console.log.

Comment: `String(error)` is the same as `.toString()`. It doesn't give a nice output when working with traditional objects.

Comment: In general, you can't. `console.log` (or `console` generally, for that matter) isn't actually in the specification, implementers are free to serialise or otherwise display the provided values as they see fit. But if you _only_ care about Deno: https://deno.land/api@v1.28.2?s=Deno.inspect.

Comment: The `Deno.inspect` function is perfect for what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console behaviour isn't defined by the ECMAScript specification, so a given runtime can implement that however its maintainers see fit. E.g. quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console):

> The specifics of how it works varies from browser to browser, but
> there is a *de facto* set of features that are typically provided.

Deno does expose [the `inspect` function](https://deno.land/api@v1.28.2?s=Deno.inspect):

> `inspect(value: unknown, options?: InspectOptions): string`
>
> Converts the input into a string that has the same format as printed
> by `console.log()`.

Node has [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) which is similar, although not explicitly tied to the console behaviour:

> The `util.inspect()` method returns a string representation of object
> that is intended for debugging.